# Change the key binding in Microsoft Wireless keyboard under Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, key-binding

I have a Microsoft Wireless keyboard.

It uses one key for both `Pause/Break` and `Scroll Lock`. You can switch between them using `F Lock`.

For functional keys to work, `F Lock` should be on which turns this button into `Scroll Lock` mode.

However, I use `Break` much more often, so each time I need to press it I need to press `F Lock` then `Break` then `F Lock` again.

Can I change the key binding somehow so that when `F Lock` is on, the button is a `Break`, and when it's off, the button is a `Scroll Lock`?

**Update:**

The `Break` is quite a special key: it sends a `6`-byte scancode `(E1 1D 45 E1 9D C5)` on press and nothing on release.

I wasn't able to remap it using `SharpKeys`.

Answer (score 2):

There are various tools for remapping keys in Windows.  You need to map your `Break` key to `Scroll Lock` and vice versa.

You can alter key mappings permanently by setting particular Registry keys.  I have used [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) to do this and found it easy to use.

If you want something more advanced there is [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/#).  This allows you to do simple key mappings like SharpKeys but also has a scripting language.  This means you can do things like make remapping only work in certain applications or make a singe keystroke do several things.  If you have a [look on LifeHacker there are various AutoHotKey scripts](http://lifehacker.com/search/autohotkey/) which will give you an idea of how powerful it can be.

Comment: I tried to use `SharpKeys`, however the `Break` key is quite special: it actually sends a `6`-byte scan code which `SharpKeys` don't seem to be able to remap.

Comment: Did you reboot or log in and out after setting the mapping in SharpKeys?  IIRC you need to do that to make Windows re-read the Registry keys.  Or is the Break key just not listed?  Otherwise from the documentation is looks like AutoHotKey does support Break: autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

Comment: Yes, I logged out and back. `Break` is not listed and when you press it it is recognized as `NumLock`. `AutoHotKey` recognizes the `Break` but pressing it seems to pause the script. Can I turn hotkey support off somehow so that a hotkey don't affect `AutoHotKey` itself?

Comment: Hmmm... I guess if Break is special it might be operating at low level which AutoHotKey can't interrupt.  How about mapping ScrollLock to Break and something like WindowsKey+ScrollLock to ScrollLock.  Then you can use ScrollLock if you need to but don't need to try and remap Break.

Answer (score 1):

Give [AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/) a shot, you can do custom remapping. compile the script and start at boot.

Answer (score 1):

Especially for you: [Keyboard remap – Pause Break key as DEL key](http://www.neox.net/w/2008/02/13/keyboard-remap-pause-break-key-as-del-key/)